# Why I can't set vertical-align middle for hr tag

Tags: html, css

I have title in h2, left and right is defined hr.
I can't position hr to be towards the middle of h2.
On JSfiddle looks good, but in my case looks like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/prc0g.png

I tried to write vertical-align:middle, but hr goes down, and I deleted.
HTML

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,200,300,500,600,700,800,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<hr class="hrtitle"/><h2 class="fontraleway">WHO WE ARE?</h2><hr class="hrtitle"/>
```

CSS

```
.fontraleway{
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
h2{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color:#333434;
    display: inline-block;

}
.hrtitle{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1px;
    background-color:#3eb8df;
    border:none;
    width:30px;

}
```

Code on JSFIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/x86o57rc/

Comment: maybe wrap hr, h2 in a div so it isolate anything that can affect the element?

Comment: Could you show your real case when?

Comment: I solved this, I remove vertical-align:middle; , and add margin-top:0px !important;
 margin-bottom:9px !important;
Do you know how to center this h2 element.
http://jsfiddle.net/x86o57rc/
I set text-align:center, but not working

Comment: Answer your question and mark the answer. Open a new question for the other problem.

Comment: @RS92 `display:inline-block` automatically makes the h2 as wide as its contents, so then it won't matter how you align the contents in it.